# How to inject HTML inside of a partial (using HAML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partials

I have a partial that represents a header that I want to place on some of my pages. Each page, though, has a different title. I want to 'inject' this title into the partial.

Here's what I'm trying to do, although it's not working:

```
= render :partial => "section_head_top"
    %span( id= "section_head_header") Apply
    = render :partial => "section_head_divider"
```

Section_head_top partial code:

```
  #section_head
      #section_head_top
          #section_head_content
```

I want the %span line to be inside of the section_head_content div. I am getting "syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end" for two lines outside of my code (even when the bottom partial is removed).

How is this done?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a local variable in your partial. For example, if your partial code looks something like this (_section_head_top.haml):

```
- title ||= 'Default Header'
#section_head
  #section_head_top
    #section_head_content
    %span( id => "section_head_header")= title
    = render :partial => "section_head_divider"
```

You can call this from your code:

```
= render :partial => "section_head_top", :locals => { :title => 'Apply' }
```